# Cloudera 5.11.0 installation on ubuntu 16.04 error: Signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cm xenial-cm5.11.0 InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:5 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease       
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                   
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]        
Fetched 306 kB in 0s (443 kB/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cm/dists/xenial-cm5.11.0/InRelease: Signature by key F36A89E33CC1BD0F71079007327574EE02A818DD uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

When trying to install the latest cloudera 5.11.0, I get the following error. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: I just realized, this is just a warning and not the reason its impossible to install anything from this repository (as of 2017-04-24). The Packages file @ https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/dists/xenial-cdh5/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages is empty. So apt has no idea what packages are in the repository.